# How to obtain a grid of equal height list items?

Tags: grid, height, css

I am trying to do a grid of products using list items and `inline-block`. The problem is: the content of the blocks have variable heights and the `inline-block` doesn't keep the heights equal.

The code:

```
#blocks ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

#blocks li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:280px;
  background-color:#ff9933;
  padding:13px;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 19px;
}

<div id="blocks">
    <ul>
       <li>...</li>
       <li>...</li>
       <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Here's an image to illustrate the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AtFt.jpg)

I need the blocks to keep the same height of the larger blocks, independently of its content. Is it possible to make someting like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/impXC.jpg)?

And finally: **Sorry, english is not my mother language :)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1.** Adding the following to the `li` CSS will mimic the image example you provided.

```
    height: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    overflow:auto;
```

**2.** Also, here are some other approaches:

- http://demo.smartnetzone.com/same-height-columns-using-jquery/
- http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/
- http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for answering. The second link you posted has some ways of how to do what I need. I'll try the javascript method. Don't know if is the best way, but... let's see :)

Comment: Glad I could help but you should try to make Google your friend: https://www.google.com/#q=list+item+column+equal+height

Comment: unless `height:<pixels>;` is relative there is no reason to include `min-height:<pixels>;`

Answer (score 7):

There's a W3C candidate layout called "flexbox" that takes care of this problem and many others. To achieve the equal height boxes you would simply assign the property `display: flex` to the UL and `display: block` to the LIs inside it.

[Example](http://cdpn.io/bKyzv)  (CodePen)

It's not going to get you very far if you need to support older browsers :) but if you can get around that this method is easy and super cool.

Reference: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Can you do this and centralize vertically the content inside the LIs?

Comment: Yes, you can add `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to the LIs themselves and play with that.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `justify-content: center;`, that's what makes the LI contents align to the middle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way, barring javascript, to do this; my recommendation would be to set a defined height and maybe an `overflow:auto` so in the case that content does overflow it does not cripple your site and your readers can still see your content.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As you said, Javascript is the way :)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you adjust your margin to be on all 4 sides it will space out a little better on the flow to new line.

Second, you can either specify a min-height that is closer to something common for all areas, or run JavaScript to set them to the same on a line given a particular width.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll try to do someting with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

When you have more divs and thus more rows, without row-divs (container divs that mark a row), then the following example from CSS Tricks does what you need:

[Equal Height Blocks in Rows](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/)

The following code has eight list items. When only three or four items are displayed per role, then the given example will make all divs equal in height per row.

```
<div id="blocks">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```