# Horizontal lists in CSS

Tags: css

What's the best practice for doing a horizontal list in css? Now I know this is a very basic question but the effect I'm looking for is in a website like this: http://www.frontend2011.com/.

If you scroll down to the video portion with the 4 column lists, you'll see a good use of it. But if I give something like `float: left` and `margin-left: #px;` in the CSS, my last list item always falls to the next row before not even getting close to the edge of the div box model.

I've heard it's because of the box model and the border/padding/margin but what's the best way to get past this? I would like the lists to touch the right and left sides of the div but this seems impossible for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this could be a good use of `box-sizing` property (supported by all browser, IE8 included): given an unordered list (and assuming list-items all with the same height) you can assign this style to every `<li>`:

```
li {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;

   float   : left;
   width   : 25%;
   padding : 15px; /* this will be applied internally, due to 
                      box-sizing property */

}
```

then if you want to force a clearing after every 4<sup>th</sup> `li`, just add

```
li:nth-child(4n) { 
   clear : left; 
}
```

otherwise, if you can't be sure that every `<li>` have always the same height then use `inline-block` position instead of `float`.

Comment: I seen that li:nth-child(4n){ clear:left } used in the same website. But that one confuses me.

Comment: let say that if you have a container with a fluid width and you if you want to be sure to always display 4 items per-row then you should specify that rule, otherwise in a container of a fixed width it is not really necessary

Answer (score 2):

You want to first zero out the `margin` and `padding`, so you no longer have the indention inherent in a list. (Note, you should probably make this specific through a class, ie, `ul class="horizontal"`).

Then, float `li` and give it a width that's relative (in pixel or percent) to the `ul` width. Accounting for the `margin` between the `li`s can be more difficult for percentage widths, though, if you want an absolute (for example, `1px`) separation.

**EDIT** - I forgot to add the last minute addition of the `.horizontal` class to all of the selectors.

And with the full box effect: http://jsfiddle.net/MYLGv/9/

```
<ul class="horizontal">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
</ul>

ul.horizontal,
ul.horizontal li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.horizontal {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 400px;
    background: whiteSmoke;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.horizontal li {
    float: left;
    width: 99px;
    height: 99px;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG) center center no-repeat;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MYLGv/8/

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to display a list horizontally.

1) You can set the `li`:s to `display: inline`, inline elements' width, height and padding can not be styled the same way block elements can so if you want backgrounds or borders you should use:

2) `display: inline-block` displays the `li`:s on one line while keeping the features of a block element, `inline-block` works in most browsers but you may need to use `*display: inline` for IE7 and below. `inline` and `inline-block` elements are affected by line-height and font-size and you may get unwanted gaps between your menu items, you can easily solve this by setting the `font-size` to 0 on the `ul` and setting it back to normal in the `li`:s.

3) Thirdly you can use `display: block` together with `float: left`, problem with float is that it can't be centered like `display: inline-block` easily can with `text-align: center` *and* you have to remember to clear the parent element (`overflow: hidden` on the `ul` is enough)

4) If you need your list to span the entire width of its parent, the easiest thing you can do is use `display: table; width: 100%` on the `ul` and `display: table-cell` on the `li`:s, making the `ul` behave just like a `table`

Comment: If you use `float: left/right`, you don't need `display: block` with it.

Comment: Well, list elements are by default `display: list-item`, but that's true, `display: block` makes no difference. But, if you use `inline` or `inline-block` you never need to use `float`

Comment: awesome examples Jared and Powerbuoy. And thanks for not judging me on being a newb and provide quality feedback to something that has been a plague to me up to now. I will try these examples later on.

Answer (score 0):

That particular spot in the page you linked to uses the following CSS to make those horizontal lists.

```
.col{
    width: 24%;
    margin: 0 0 2% 1%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Your answer here is basically the same thing I said doesn't work. I've used this same code and still my last column gets pushed down. So there had to be more to this which I think Fabrizio answered above

Answer (score 0):

It's basically impossible to get this right with pure CSS and not using a table structure/javascript, also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285564/how-to-obtain-a-grid-of-equal-height-list-items).

I used the jQuery solution that is also suggested there and it works perfectly. Find the link [here](https://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/).

And here's the code:

```
var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;

 $('.blocks').each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   topPosition = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPosition) {

     // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }

     // set the variables for the new row
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPosition;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);

   } else {

     // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);

  }

  // do the last row
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }

 });​
```